# phpMyAdmin no option to edit siteURL Local wordpress to server

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

So I am in the process of migrating a WordPress site from it's local mamp to a live server. I have been following this guide mainly without issue.

However, when I reach "Step 5: Change the Site URL" in `phpMyAdmin`. 
I can see the table present but there is no option to the edit the content, I cannot change the URL for this or home.

`phpMyAdmin` Looks Like:

[image: phpMyAdminLooksLike]

Comment: if you have just those 2 records in your table, you can just `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = "https:\/\/yourdomain.com" WHERE option_value = "http:\/\/localhost"`

Comment: I have around 600+ values in the table

Answer (score 0):

this because your export and import database not successfully complete

i suggest re export from Healthy database and import that

but if you don’t want that, you can edit siteurl with sql command

```
UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = example.com
WHERE option_name = siteurl;
```

Comment: You hero! Deleted table, re-exported, re-imported and it is present. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. The thing is : The very table you intend to modify has no **Primary key**. Until you have one, you have no possibility as to proceed further unless you use SQL commands as it was mentionned before